# How do I safely uninstall unused ubuntu installs

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, uninstall

Im trying to clean up my drive as I've got some duplicates of 11.10 installed. My original install was messed up so I reinstalled (foolishly thinking it would just write over the original).
I lived with it for a while before deciding to delete the partition to use the space as a storage for files I also want in windows (its a dual boot). After deleting the partition and updating grub (grub said everything was fine). I rebooted, only to be faced with grub rescue. After another install I've still got two ubuntu's. Someone please help....

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys, will give it a shot once I retrieve my live usb.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use only `update-grub2` after deleting the partition? 
If that is the case then after deleting another partition, try `sudo grub-install /dev/sdx` where `sdx` is the HDD where the current Ubuntu installation resides.e.g. `sda` if first hard disk. Then do a `sudo update-grub2`. In this way, you'll be sure that you are updating the grub from current installation and not the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Go CD or USB live, open **Gparted** and you will ave a complete table of your partitions,
from there **erase the partition you want to remove** and **expand to full disk the partition you want to keep**.

T be sure to not face again grub rescue type in terminal:

> sudo grub-install /dev/**sdx**

where **sdx** stands for the name of your disk, example:

> sudo grub-install /dev/sda

then run:

> sudo update-grub

and everything will be all fine.